# Index for tables to get non-soft-deleted items faster?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Suppose a MySQL / InnoDB table with 10 columns and a couple hundred thousand rows. One of the columns indicates if the row has been deleted, e.g. `deletedDateTime TIMESTAMP NULL`. When non-null, the row has been soft-deleted.

Is there an index which would make these tables perform better, given that almost all queries filter out soft-deleted items by doing `AND deletedDateTime IS NULL`?

Comment: Please provide the full table description and examples of queries that either perform slowly or are meant to be executed very often (that's where indexes will make the most difference). Indexing is a complete subject that must be thought of case by case. Also keep in mind that if indexing can improve reading performance, it also decreases writing performance because the index needs to be updated when the table is. The reading / writing frequency ratio of your table is important to determine whether it should be heavily or lightly indexed.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the slow query.

Answer (score 1):

The index by `(deletedDateTime)` must increase the queries performance. But if the amount of rows which matches `deletedDateTime TIMESTAMP NULL` is over 5-7% then this index won't be effective, and server won't use it. If you'd force its usage then the query will be slower with high probability.

For most queries you'd create indices where `(deletedDateTime)` is a prefix or at least a part of the index expression.

If you'd decide to define this column as NOT NULL and use some constant date literal in far future as a mark that the row is not deleted ('2038-01-19', for example) then use `WHERE deletedDateTime = '2038-01-19'` instead of checking for NULL. This will additionally improve your queries slightly. Of course in addition to the index creation described above.

Also you may create (virtual, invisible) generated column by the expression `(deletedDateTime IS NULL)` and index by this column (or use it as index prefix) - this must provide the best improvement. But your server version must be 8.0.23 or newer. Alternatively you may try the index by the expression.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test and see if any of those options help.